# Compare values from two different stores in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have two data structures:

1. Tasks: taskID (autoincremented), title, status, dueDate, description
2. Tags: tagID, tagName, tagColor, textColor, taskID

I'm trying to compare the taskID value of both of them, to later be able to associate a single task with multiple tags. I've written two functions, getTags() and getTasks(). I've managed to loop through both of them, getting all objects in both stores, however, i'm not quite sure how to check if the two values match.

```
function connectToDB() {
    window.webkitIndexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

    //check for support
    if(!window.indexedDB) {
        alert("Your browser do not support indexedDB. Please update you browser.")
    }

    //open database "KanbanDatabase" version 9. 
    //db = database, tx = transaction, store = store data, index = index (seach data).
    let request = window.indexedDB.open("KanbanDatabase", 9), 
        db,
        tx,
        store,
        index;

    //when creating a new databse, a store(structure) must be added
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
        let db = request.result,
        //tasks
        tasksStore = db.createObjectStore("tasksStore",{
            keyPath: "taskID", autoIncrement: true
        }),
        tasksIndex = tasksStore.createIndex("status", "status", {
            unique: false
        }),
        //tags
        tagsStore = db.createObjectStore("tagsStore", {
            keyPath: "tagID", autoIncrement: true
        }),
        tagsIndex = tagsStore.createIndex("tagID", "tagID", {
            unique: true
        });
    };

    //open database will return response. 
    //error handler:
    request.onerror = function(e) {
        console.error("There was an error opening the database: " + e.target.errorCode);
    };

    //success handler:
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        console.log("Successfully connected to DB")
        db = request.result;
        //tasks
        tasksTx = db.transaction("tasksStore", "readwrite");
        tasksStore = tasksTx.objectStore("tasksStore");
        tasksIndex = tasksStore.index("status");

        //tags
        tagsTx = db.transaction("tagsStore", "readwrite");
        tagsStore = tagsTx.objectStore("tagsStore");
        tagsIndex = tagsStore.index("tagID");

        db.onerror = function(e) {
            console.error("ERROR " + e.target.errorCode);
        }


        function tagsToTasks() {
            let amountOfTasks = tasksIndex.count();
            let amountOfTags = tagsIndex.count();

            function getTasks() {
                for (var i = 1; i < amountOfTasks.result+1; i++) {
                    let getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);

                    getTasks.onerror = function() {
                        console.error("There was an error looping through the tasks");
                    }

                    getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
                        console.log(getTasks.result.taskID)
                    }
                }
            }

            function getTags() {
                for (var j = 1; j < amountOfTags.result+1; j++) {
                    let getTags = tagsStore.get(j);

                    getTags.onerror = function() {
                        console.error("There was en error looping through the tags");
                    }

                    getTags.onsuccess = function() {
                        let result = getTags.result.taskID;

                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }

            function compareID() {
                //what to do?
            }

            amountOfTasks.onerror = function() {
                console.error("There was an error finding the amount of tasks");
            }

            amountOfTasks.onsuccess = function() {
                getTasks();
            }

            amountOfTags.onerror = function() {
                console.error("There was an error finding the amount of tags");
            }

            amountOfTags.onsuccess = function() {
                getTags();
            }

        }


        //fire functions
        tagsToTasks();
        listTasks();

        //close DB conection once transaction is complete.
        tasksTx.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        }

        tagsTx.oncomplete = function() {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** to clarify: I need to compare two values in two different stores. The problem starts in the tagsToTasks() function; how can i compare the values returned from getTags.result.taskID in the getTags() function to the getTasks.result.taskID in the getTasks() function?

Comment: There's an error here. `window.webkitIndexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;` You are assigning it to `window.webkitIndexedDb` but working with `window.indexedDb`

Comment: Sorry, thought it would add context. Should be reduced now. @AvinKavish.

Answer (score 0):

First error is here.

```
window.webkitIndexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;`
```

You are assigning it to `window.webkitIndexedDb` but checking for `window.indexedDb` in the next line.

I'd suggest using a local const instead of attempting to overwrite global variables.

Like so,

```
const indexedDb = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;

if (!indexedDb) return ....
```

Next, you can use a `cursor` or the `getAll` method to retrieve all objects. Also, you can't return the task from the `onSuccess` event handler, you need to assign it a variable from a parent scope. Like so,

```
let tasks = [];
tasksStore.getAll().onsuccess = function(event) {
   tasks = event.target.result
   attachTags(tasks);
};

function attachTags(tasks) {
  tags.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
    const task = tasks.find(t => t.taskId == cursor.value.taskId);
    if (!task.tags) task.tags = []
       task.tags.push(cursor.value) ;
    cursor.continue();
  }
  else {
    return;
  }
};
}
```

looks like you will have to go through callback hell to do this. I'm using the `find` method to pick the task with the taskId of the current tag pointed by the `cursor` at `cursor.value` and then I'm creating an array of tags for that task and pushing the tags into it. Looking at your data model, I assumed you wanted to associate each tag with the relevant task through the taskId foreign key.

The problem with the way you've set up things is that indexedDB uses callbacks to return values and nowhere in your code are you saving these values and passing on to the functions that need them. You've written callbacks that essentially do nothing with the values they receive. You cannot return a value out of a callback, because the callback gets called by the API, not your code. you need to assign values to variables outside the callback or do the processing inside the callback. Callbacks execute asynchronously to each other so there is no guarantee that your code will execute in the sequence you've written it in, which leaves you with no choice but to setup the next callback from the current callback, this is referred to as callback hell. Promises help alleviate this, so if you are going to use this in production, I would recommend a library such as this 
https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb that exposes a more usable Api.

Comment: Thank you! I've fixed this now. I'm not sure if I was unclear in my original question, but I need to compare two values in two different stores. The problem starts in the ```tagsToTasks()``` function; how can i compare the values returned from ```getTags.result.taskID``` in the ```getTags()``` function to the ```getTasks.result.taskID``` in the ```getTasks()``` function?

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation! I see now why the original way wouldn't work. I'm just playing around with IndexedDB, so it will not be used on a live site. I do, however, get an error with your code. On ```tags.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {``` i get the error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: tags is not defined```.

How would I go about, for example, displaying this appended in a div through dom?

Comment: Yeah it wasn't meant to be copy & paste code, I was referring to `tagsStore`. That's a whole different question. tbh, I think you have a long way to go before you play with indexedDb, it is an obscure and rarely used feature, because any serious application saves data on a backend server. This should get you started on DOM manipulation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents